# Displaying data horizontally with no scroll bar

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I need to build a list of strings with a checkbox next to each one of them. I want to build it horizontally, but I don't want a horizontal scroll bar to appear. I was thinking of using either a Repeater or a DataList for the task, but how do I wrap the data to prevent a scroll bar to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the CheckBoxList but set the repeatdirection to be horizontal and set the container to a specified width but not a specified height.

Comment: I'm sure it'll help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.repeatdirection.aspx

Comment: The reason I was thinking about using a repeater was that I wanted to group the items under their first letter, which I can't do in a checkboxlist. Maybe I'll skip it the grouping if I can't find a better solution.

Comment: You could still do the grouping. I'll give you a second hint: Use the code initially generated by this as a template/concept. That's an option too.

Comment: I've created a CheckBoxList bound to my data list. I tried seting it's width and the width of div it's placed in but it still gives me one long horizontal line.

Comment: Did you review the link I provided in my second comment?

Comment: Scratch that. I had to change the RepeatLayout to Flow. I'll check out your suggestion about the grouping as well. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You can place all of your controls inside this Div

```
<div style="overflow:scroll;overflow-x:hidden; height:300px;"></div>
```

I Hope this will resolve your problem.